# Error when uploading .ipa to iTunes Visual Studio Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, itunes-store

I have visual studio 2015.Cordova 6 ios platform 4.0.1. I can't upload ipa to iTunes, I have problem for two days and still couldnt solve it.

> ERROR ITMS-900032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path
>   referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFile': 'icon.png'

I read similar problems in stack overflow no one solved my problem.

```
 <platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </platform>
```

above is my config.xml these ,Please help me about this problem. I am getting crazy for 2 days to see same problem.

Answer (score 0):

A known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10493

The Cordova 6.1.1 should have the fix. Change the Cordova version in config.xml designer in VS.
[image]